# TestNG add custom Listeners to build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, testng, build.gradle

Is there a way to provide your own custom listener for testng using the build.gradle file? For example:

```
useTestNG() {
  addTestListener(new CustomListener)
}
```

CustomListener is defined as this in the project:

```
public class CustomListener implements IInvokedMethodListener
```

We don't want to have to rely on adding the `@Listener` annotation to each of our test classes to use our listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 test {
     useTestNG() {
         listeners << 'your.package.name.CustomListener'
     }
 }
```

---

**Reference**

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/using-testng-with-gradle